# How was the A-Team funded?

Tags: the-a-team

According to the [Wikipedia article on *The A-Team*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_A-Team#Characters):

> The A-Team was an American action-adventure television series that ran on NBC from 1983 to 1987 about former members of a fictitious United States Army Special Forces unit. The members, after being court-martialed "for a crime they didn't commit", escaped from military prison and, while still on the run, worked as soldiers of fortune.

**Question:** How was the A-team funded?

Comment: They have the same credit card the scooby doo gang uses to fund their adventures. Must be either the best credit company on earth or the worst.

Comment: @KaiQing +1 for scooby doo ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The fortune part of “soldiers of fortune” means they charge for their services.

Remember the final line of the intro narration: “If you’ve got a problem, and if you can find them, maybe you can **hire** The A-team”.

Comment: Their usual fee is two acetylene cylinders, 400 rounds of blank ammunition, one gold chain, and one huge cigar.

Comment: @Snow And a gallon of milk.

Comment: And there's probably a clause or two regarding the [use of planes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DaJOeLuUD94)

Comment: Oh, and a dose of sleeping tablets...

Comment: Also you need to have convenient ramp-like structures around your local area for handy vehicular side-flips...

Answer (score 1):

As Todd stated, the term "Soldiers of Fortune" implies that they are paid for their services.  However, not every episode was a paycheck for The A-Team.  In some episodes, they did work for free as they would, from time to time, come across bad guys by accident.  In at least one episode, the entire show centered around getting BA to a hospital to treat a wound, while avoiding Colonel Lynch, the head MP tasked with capturing them.  Lynch was replaced by Colonel Decker after Season 1.